# Выделение окончания в неизменяемом существительном

Tags: окончания

Вопрос по разбору слова «полпятого»

На одном сайте вижу такое:

Разбор слова по составу онлайн:
корень *ПОЛ*; корень *ПЯТ*; окончание *ОГО*. 
Основа слова *ПОЛПЯТ*.

Вычисленный способ образования слова Бессуфиксальный или другой.

А на другом — такое:

Окончание всегда указывает на изменяемость слова. Неизменяемые слова лишены окончания, поскольку у них нет соотносимых с ними форм, у которых бы появилось материально выраженное окончание.

Как у неизменяемого существительного может быть окончание, ведь не должно его быть?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

> Окончание всегда указывает на изменяемость слова...

Есть окончание и у слова ***полпятого***.

См. [***"Русскую грамматику"***](http://rusgram.narod.ru/1173-1193.html):

> **§ 1193.** Особую группу слов составляют сложные существительные с
>   первым компонентом *пол-*, в исходной форме которых вторым компонентом
>   является порядковое прилагательное в **род. п.**: *полвторого,
>   полтретьего, полчетвертого, полпятого* и т. д. до *полдвенадцатого*.
>   Эти слова называют время суток. Сферой их употребления является
>   разговорная речь; в нормативной литературной речи им соответствуют
>   сочетания со словом *половина: половина второго, половина третьего,
>   половина четвертого.* Слова этой группы, как правило, не изменяются по
>   падежам. **Исключение составляет дат. п., имеющий вариантную
>   просторечную форму**: *(к) полвторого* и *к полвторому, (к)
>   полтретьего* и *(к) полтретьему, (к) полпятого* и *(к) полпятому.*
>   Парадигма таких слов имеет следующий вид: **им. п.**: *полчетвертого;*
>   **род. п.**: *(до) полчетвертого;* **дат. п.**: *(к) полчетвертого* **и прост.** *(к) полчетвертому;* **вин. п.**: *(в) полчетвертого;* **тв.** и **предл. п.** в употреблении редки *(перед полчетвертого, о полчетвертого).*

Answer (score 0):

Зачем лишняя казуистика? У "полпятого" происхождение слова еще не затуманилось, как у "куличек", "тормашек" или "бекреня". У числительного "пятый" окончание есть, у "пятого" тоже есть. Поэтому и у "полпятого" вполне просматривается.

Answer (score 0):

А меду прочим, вопрос интересный, если в корень посмотреть. 
Термин "окончание", его определение, на самом деле не так прост, как может показаться. Если взять школьное определение типа "изменяемая [при склонении и т.п.] часть слова", то возникают подобные коллизии, например со словами, находящимися в стадии переразложения. Когда и если "полпятого" признают полноценным наречием, то и окончания его лишат. Но пока этого не произошло, разложение слова идет по линии "пол+пятого" - т.е. присоединения префикса (приставки? корня? - не столь важно) к существующему слову "пятого", которое имеет полноценный корень и флексию. В этом Niemand прав (хотя формулировки у него и примитивны).

Вот я не могу понять, почему академическая(!) грамматика признаеь эти образавания существительными... Разве они в своем родиденом падеже отвечают на вопрос "кого или чего?" а не "какого/которого?" или, в крайнем случае, "сколько?"???